# How would I insert data into an Access table using vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access, insert

I want to insert a new row into an Access database. I'm looking at doing something like:

```
oConnection = new Connection("connectionstring")
oTable = oCennection.table("Orders")
oRow = oTable.NewRow
oRow.field("OrderNo")=21
oRow.field("Customer") = "ABC001"
oTable.insert
```

Which seems to be a sensible way of doing things to me.

However, All examples I look for on the net seem to insert data by building SQL statements, or by creating a "SELECT * From ...", and then using this to create a multitude of objects, one of which appears to allow you to ...
- populate an array with the current contents of the table.
- insert a new row into this array.
- update the database with the changes to the array.

What's the easiest way of using vb.net to insert data into an Access database?
Is there a method I can use that is similar to my pCode above?

Comment: Are you running your code in Access? If not, then your question is not an Acccess question at all, since all you're using is a Jet database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way:

```
cn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\emp.mdb;")
cn.Open()
str = "insert into table1 values(21,'ABC001')"
cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, cn)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
```

I would make a dataset, add a tableadapter connected to the Access database, then let the tableadapter create update/delete/modify for me. Then you just could do like this (assuming your database has a usertable and you mapped that up in the dataset):

```
    Dim UserDS As New UserDS
    Dim UserDA As New UserDSTableAdapters.UsersTableAdapter
    Dim NewUser As UserDS.UsersRow = UserDS.Users.NewUsersRow

    NewUser.UserName = "Stefan"
    NewUser.LastName = "Karlsson"

    UserDS.User.AddUserRow(NewUser)

    UserDA.Update(UserDS.Users)
```

Comment: I needed to add "UserDS.User.AddUserRow(NewUser)" before the Update Line to make that work.

Answer (score 1):

how to insert the string in vb.net only insert in the integer my pgm is

```
Try
    cn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\db1.mdb;")
    cn.Open()
    str = "insert into table1 values(" & CInt(t2.Text) & ",'" & (t1.Text) & ") "
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, cn)
    icount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
    MessageBox.Show("stored")
Catch
End Try
cn.Close()
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, the world doesn't re-arrange itself to suit how you think it should work.  If you want to work with a database, it's a good idea to get at least somewhat comfortable with SQL, as that is generally how it's done.

On the bright side, there is a whole category of products that do kind of what you want.  You can look for an Object-Relational Mappings (ORM) tool like ActiveRecord, NHibernate, or LINQ.  But still learn some SQL.